# Migration from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 error message

Tags: swift, migration, swift3, swift2

I have been trying to migrate Swift project to latest Swift version.

```
fileprivate lazy var _uploadedSurveysController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

This code line gives the following error.

```
Nil cannot initialize the specified type NSFetchedResultsController?
```

Xcode comes up with a fix recommendation which is adding another question mark next to NSFetchedResultsController. When i say yes, it gives the same error and coming up with a fix adding another question mark.

Here is more code

```
fileprivate var uploadedSurveysController: NSFetchedResultsController {
guard _uploadedSurveysController == nil else { return _uploadedSurveysController! }

 _uploadedSurveysController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest:     coreDataHelper.mailedAssetsFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext:   managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "section2Identifier", cacheName: nil)

do {
  try _uploadedSurveysController!.performFetch()
} catch let error as NSError { Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function)     Uploaded Surveys Fetching Error: \(error.userInfo)") }

 return _uploadedSurveysController!
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Just to let you know. I am really new to Swift and trying to update an existing project from Swift 2.3 to 3.

Thanks in advance.
Remzi.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` in Swift 3 needs a generic type declaration now. 

Can you include some more code where `_uploadedSurveysController` is used? (Initialised as not being `nil`)

Comment: Just try by removing '= nil' as your variable is already optional and can be nil or something so whenever you are going to use, you will check for nil before using this controller.

Comment: Hi Anni, i took '= nil' out but didnt do anything, different errors came up.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same error message after upgrading a Swift 2 project to Swift 3. Lazy instantiation has become simpler in Swift so there is no need for the hidden _variableName property any longer.

If you add the lazy attribute your property definition can you can then specify a function block to run to initialise it should the property ever be set to nil.

```
fileprivate lazy var uploadedSurveysController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {

    var fetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: coreDataHelper.mailedAssetsFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext:   managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "section2Identifier", cacheName: nil)

    do {
      try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError { Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function)     Uploaded Surveys Fetching Error: \(error.userInfo)") }

     return fetchedResultsContoller
}()
```

I found a good description on lazy instantiation in Swift in [a blog entry by Mike Buss](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is more code.

```
fileprivate var uploadedSurveysController: NSFetchedResultsController {
guard _uploadedSurveysController == nil else { return _uploadedSurveysController! }

_uploadedSurveysController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: coreDataHelper.mailedAssetsFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "section2Identifier", cacheName: nil)

do {
  try _uploadedSurveysController!.performFetch()
} catch let error as NSError { Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function) Uploaded Surveys Fetching Error: \(error.userInfo)") }

return _uploadedSurveysController!
```

}

Comment: You should edit the original question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the `lazy` designation, which follows different rules than a standard property.  Since you've already implemented lazy instantiation on your own, the `lazy` keyword is unnecessary (and it's not intended for use in this manner anyway).  Try removing it and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Bob, i have tried it but still seems the same error. Xcode comes up adding another question mark to fix it.

Comment: By the way i just removed lazy but left '= nil'.